# Emploi du participe présent (Via Mala, de John Knittel, Albin Michel, p. 469)

Tags: participe-présent

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> Il ressentait péniblement l'absence de Sylvelie. Où était-elle en ce moment? Attendant, avec sa famille?

Il me semble que l'usage du participe présent dans la seconde question est incorrect. Il s'agirait d'un anglicisme. Est-ce que quelqu'un peut confirmer que cet usage est incorrect et expliquer pourquoi ?

Comment: Au moins maladroit. Naturel: "en train d'attendre".

Comment: Ce qui parait incorrect, c'est que "attendant" voudrait un cod, qui n'est pas présent.

Comment: @Frank Même avec un cod, je ne trouve pas cette construction correcte.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse "repêcher" cette expression ici effectivement, même avec un cod. Elle semble être la traduction directe de "waiting" en anglais. Mais l'oreille attendrait un cod en général. Par exemple, "attendant la pluie". Le titre "En attendant Godot" vient à l'esprit. Mais là, il y a la particule "en", et l'expression est bien différente.

Comment: @Frank C'est ce que je soupçonnait : il n'existerait pas d'usage rare pour expliquer cette proposition (similaire à usage courant suivant (qui, celui-ci, n'est pas rare) : « que pensait-elle faire ? Attendre avec sa famille? »). Je comprends, il faut changer la forme ; il faudrait ce que vous avez écrit ailleurs (« En train d'attendre… »). Le gérondif de « En attendant Godot » implique une simultanéité qui n'a pas d'incidence dans « Attendant avec sa famille » ; le gérondif ne sert en effet à rien pour améliorer cette construction.

Comment: @LPH quelle est la version originale de cet extrait ?

Comment: @guillaume31 La version originale est en anglais (mais je n'ai pas pu me la procurer) et l'extrait provient d'une traduction (par Denise Van Moppès).

Comment: @guillaume31 Je viens de m'apercevoir que c'est de vous que je tenais le nom de la traductrice. Négliger ce détail dans le commentaire ci-dessus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'utilisation du participe présent sans COD ne me choque pas. On peut dire :

> - Comment t'imagines-tu ta grand-mère à cet instant de sa vie ?
>
> - Attendant, avec sa famille. Elle ne pouvait pas faire grand chose d'autre.
>
> -> Je me l'imagine attendant, avec sa famille.

"Attendre", même transitif, a un emploi absolu : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attendre II. B.

Ce qui froisse davantage l'oreille dans l'exemple, c'est que la phrase répond à "**où** était-elle ?" et qu'on s'attend à un complément de lieu ou tout au moins un groupe qui puisse compléter "elle était".

> - Où était-elle à ce moment ?
>
> ~ Attendant, avec sa famille.
>
> -> <strike>Elle était attendant, avec sa famille</strike>

Le point de vue selon lequel il y a rupture de logique peut donc se défendre. Si l'on admet cette hypothèse, il peut aussi bien s'agir d'une - légère - anacoluthe (rupture de construction involontaire ou stylistiquement assumée) que d'un anglicisme participant du même effet. La cause est difficile à déterminer.

Comment: Cette récupération, pour employer le mot de user Frank ci-dessus, m'est, il me semble, assez familière, mais pas sans un cod ou un complément.  Par Example « Je me l'imagine travaillant. » me semble bizarre, alors que « Je me l'imagine travaillant à sa botanique et prenant soin de ses roses. » me semble être normal. Néanmoins, la seconde partie correspond  à mon impression : l'emploi dans *Via Mala* ne serait pas correct.

Comment: L'attente peut être une posture physique perçue par un observateur, sans qu'il sache ce qui est attendu :) Ou ce qui est attendu peut être omis volontairement parce qu'on s'appuie sur le contexte. Dans ce cas, un COD n'est pas nécessaire.

Comment: 1/ Je manque peut-être de familiarité avec la construction sans complément ; il se peut qu'elle devienne normale dans mon esprit, un jour. 2/ Finalement, selon votre suggestion, on devrait concevoir cette phrase comme contenant une ellipse (« Était-elle attendant, avec sa famille ? ») et il ne s'agirait alors pas d'autre chose que d'un anglicisme flagrant.

Comment: L'anglicisme n'est pas à exclure, mais c'est difficile de commenter un choix de traduction, cela peut très bien être délibéré. D'un autre côté, la traductrice est signalée comme française par les sources (cf commentaires sur une autre question concernant ce livre) mais semble accumuler les maladresses de formulation. C'est assez étrange.

Comment: @LPH j'ai clarifié ma réponse et inclus plus d'explications possibles

Comment: Le point de vue de cette réponse n'est pas catégorique, mais il ne ferme pas la porte à mon impression d'un certain manque d'idiomaticité, et donc bien qu'assez arbitrairement vu cet état de chose, je vais l' « accepter ».

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, cet usage ne me choque pas du tout.
C'est littéraire, certes, mais pas choquant.
Ici, le participe présent se confond très bien avec le présent progressif anglais.
Sylvelie est (peut-être) en train d'attendre, peut-être avec sa famille.

Quand à l'absence de COD, repenser à la chanson de Goldman :
« *Aussi grands que celui qu'elle attend, elle attend* »

Comment: Ce n'est pas le genre de chose qui me choque dans le langage, c'est plutôt un cas de chose qui me laisse dans une sorte de « vide informationnel », une chose sur laquelle mon habitude de la langue  me laisse tomber, pour ainsi dire.

Answer (score 1):

Cette traduction ne (me) pose aucun problème grammatical, syntaxique ou de logique.

1. ***Attendant*** sans complément explicite est possible si le contexte suffit à comprendre ce que Sylvélie attendait, voire si le savoir n'apporte pas d'intérêt au récit.

> *C'est un acte infâme. Que fais-tu ? **J'attends**, répondit X...* (Victor Hugo, *Histoire d'un crime*, 1877)

2. ***Avec sa famille*** peut être une réponse suffisante à la question ***Où est-elle ?*** si, là aussi, le contexte indique où se trouve sa famille en ce moment.

Le sens est donc:

> Où était-elle en ce moment ? **Avec sa famille ? À attendre ?**

mais ***Attendant*** a été placé en premier pour mettre l'emphase sur cette attente plutôt que le lieu, jugé secondaire.

Comment: Quelle principe grammatical viendrait confirmer cet usage ?

Comment: *Assise auprès du feu, dévidant et filant*

Comment: @LPH quel usage ? "Attendre" est un verbe transitif mais qui peut avoir un emploi absolu (https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attendre II. B.), si c'est la question.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça n'est même pas une phrase.

Comment: @guillaume31 Le participe présent (pas en tant qu'adjectif) « sert  généralement à exprimer une _action qui s'accomplit en même temps que celle exprimée par le verbe principal_ (https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/le-participe-present-f1198). Il n'y a pas de verbe principal.

Comment: @LPH C'est une phrase parfaitement valide, par exemple comme réponse à la question *Où serez-vous quand vous serez bien vieille, au soir, à la chandelle ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Il faut donc supposer une ellipse du sujet et du verbe; ça donne « Je serais assise, filant. ». Le problème c'est que dans le texte en question l'équivalent de « assise » n'existe pas et donc il n'y a pas de verbe principal  ; ça donne « je serais attendant ». La simultanéité avec « être » n'a pas de sens; peut-être que « Je me morfondrai, attendant. » serait acceptable, bien que je ne le crois pas et je trouverais correct par exemple « Je me morfondrai en attendant. ».

Comment: Non, pas *je **serai** attendant*. La réponse est *je serai **avec ma famille***.